# while installing jupyter notebook at python 3.7.3

Tags: python

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]

```
  Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
  This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
  the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

  Checking for Rust toolchain....
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: What command did you run to install jupyter notebook? Was it `pip install notebook` as the Jupyter project [suggests](https://jupyter.org/install)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i used pip install jupyter notebook in command prompt but at end i upgrade pip command and get that error and eventually can not open jupyter as well as it gives not recognize message while trying to open jupyter

Comment: What operating system are you running?